# Rails-RMagick handle single image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a rails app where a user uploads an image, then it gets sent to rmagick to be modified and then gets rendered.  Since the user only handles one image, I was initially thinking that I could store it in memory instead of the database, but that seems to not be feasible.  The model name is AppImage, so I then thought about displaying AppImage.last and deleting all previous AppImages right before rendering it, but I'm wondering if that would cause problems with multiple users.

Is the best solution to have each user get a user profile according to their IP, and have one AppImage per user?  Should I be thinking about session hashes?

Edit:  I am currently using paperclip, but just am not sure how to structure the program.

Comment: why are you not using paperclip (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), carrierwave (https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave), or dragonfly (https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) for uploading your images? that´s really easy and you must not code everything by yourself..

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I'm using paperclip currently, but I'm saving the images to the database and I'm just not sure about how to manage the database when I only want one image per user/session.

Comment: you should also update your question name - Rails-RMagick handle single image -> maybe Rails-Paperclip instead of Rails-RMagick would be better..

Answer (score 0):

if an user uploads an image, you could set a session variable to true, and check in your uploads controller if the session variable is set or not..dependent on that you allow the user to upload an image, or not. you can set the session store to db, further you can define a range how long the session is saved.

controller:

```
def new
  @upload = YourUploadModel.new
  session[:image_uploaded] ||= true
end

def create
  if session[:image_uploaded] && session[:image_uploaded] == true
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Already uploaded an image today!"
  else
    # create your upload..
  end
end
```

app/config/initializers/session_store.rb:

```
# Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
# which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information
# (create the session table with "rails generate session_migration")
YourAppname::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, {
  expire_after: 1.days
}
```